# Howto: RF HV power supply (13,56 MHz, ~30 kV - 50 kV, 1 kW - 3 kW)

Tags: power-supply, high-voltage, high-frequency, laser, 13.56mhz

I hope you can help me on this one.
**Short recap about me**, I am a maker and I had a vocational education some 30 years ago as engineer in HV (up to 48kV) in industrial facilities. So I am aware of the risks of handling these kinds of energies.

**My Project**: I have made a high powered CO<sub>2</sub> Laser with a theoretical maximum output of 7kW.
Currently is the laser powered with 35kV DC.

The "problem" with DC is that I have to introduce the electrodes into the resonator, to power the laser. The resonator is a glass tube with 7 to 10 torr (almost vacuum) filled with CO<sub>2</sub>.

Asides of getting the insertion holes properly sealed is the main disadvantage, that the electrodes wear down, contaminates the gas and sputter molecules onto the mirrors. The contamination of gas reduces the efficiency considerably.

Even worse, the sputtered material on the mirrors makes them kind of blind, which really kills performance and introduces heat to the mirrors until they crack.
The simple way to tackle the sputter is to use the same material for the electrode as used for the coating of the mirrors. That extends the lifetime to a certain degree.

But there is a but (of course X)

This laser runs with a **folded resonator**.
So it has a size of 3-4 foot, the actual/**unfolded length of the resonator is about 21 yards**.
[image: folded laser assembly]

You can probably imagine that this requires a solid amount of mirrors ... 44 pieces. This is a lot of money you have to present each time you have to replace these.
Not to mention the tedious process of aligning these mirrors as every deviation in the mirrors sum up in total mis-alignment which on 21 yards is considerable.

**Failing to align align the mirrors renders the laser into a fancy plasma lamp**

Also using electrodes of pure gold is expensive and the replacement is at least as problematic/tedious as replacing mirrors. Almost everything has to be disassembled and the mirror plate has to be removed too. So at least the mirror plates must be re-aligned.

[image: cross-view of mirror plate and electrodes plate]

**The golden solution is a RF generator running 13,56 MHz, ~30 kV - 50 kV, 1 kW - 8 kW.**
With this setup is it not mandatory to place the electrodes in the resonator tube. You can wrap the electrode around the tube.
**No sputtering, no contamination of the gas and no wear and tear. Assemble and forget**

This also simplifies the the design.

It is possible to purchase used generators in this category from 500$ upwards.
But as maker I would love to find a DIY solution to this.

Unfortunately is my expertise in electronics more newbie level. I do some basic electronics when needed but this is way beyond my skills and I have trouble to cut my teeth on this one.

Do you have any advice, guides, literature, schematics or at best build plans to achieve my goal?

I don't know how to get started at all.

I have found insane DIY guides on high voltage and high frequency PSUs but one of the voltage, frequency and power values is always out of scope.

Comment: 7kW at 13.56MHz? That'll play merry hell with the contactless bank cards in your pocket...

Comment: @Brian But think of the contactless range. :: wakkaluba - Amateur radio uses 1 kW class HF amplifiers (with no need to get anywhere near 30 kV) so you could look for amateur radio designs. However $500 for a working source sounds like a bargain.

Comment: oh.... That might be a brain bug on my side.
With DC such a high voltage is necessary.