# Build plans for a PSU 13.56 MHz 300 W - 1000 W with adjustable voltage between 200 V - 500 V

Tags: power-supply, laser

This is a kind of continuation of a previous thread [Howto: RF HV power supply (13,56 MHz, ~30 kV - 50 kV, 1 kW - 3 kW)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554967/howto-rf-hv-power-supply-13-56-mhz-30-kv-50-kv-1-kw-3-kw)

I made the assumption that  the voltage for exciting plasma with DC co-relates to AC ...NOT!  X)

I have figured out that Paschen's Curves provide the information needed to run certain gasses in near vacuum plasma/laser tubes.

So I am looking for build plans for a PSU that provides at least 300 W and preferably can be adjusted in voltage between 200 V and 500 V, so I also can run different gases.

Does someone know of/have build plans for this purpose?

Comment: It may help to look for "RF power amplifier" rather than "power supply".

Comment: I choose PSU for a reason. When looking for an  amplifier the RF module is missing. A PSU matches best to RF generator and amplifier. The results in google are at least way better this way

Comment: >10kWpulsed lasers are available from Coherent , Northrop plans to make 100 kW ion plasma thrusters...  https://www.coherent.com/content/dam/coherent/site/en/resources/tech-notes/lasers/COHR_HeavyMetalPipeCutting_WP_0519.pdf

Comment: As with the previous question, this is basically radio ham gear (HF bands) and you might start by looking at the 807 valve (maybe the 813 is closer to your power demand.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite 'build plans' but an app note that might give some useful hints.
https://www.ixys.com/Documents/AppNotes/CO1.pdf

Not a particularly simple or cheap project to start out on.

Comment: I know this  document. I even found a build kit ... for 400$. In that case I'd rather buyy a used generator for 100$ more